# Mail not sent but no error or exception in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send an email from my Rails application.I am not getting any error and also mail is not sent.

The below are the details.
1. SMTP server working fine (confirmed as able to send mail in cmd line, ruby script and using Net::SMTP.start() in rails also.)

2. I am not getting any error in irb console and it shows below status, but mail is not sent.

   `#<<Mail::Message:4766554> Multipart: false, Headers: From: itssreenath@gmail.com, To: itssreenath@gmail.com, <SUbject: Test Mail>>`

### Configurations:

I have configured SMTP details in config/application.yml file. The below is my application.yml file

### `config/application.yml file`

```
default_host: 192.244.18.9  
default_protocol: https   
default_from: sree@gmail.com    
smtp:
    host: 192.244.18.9
```

### `config/environments/development.rb`

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp  
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,  
    :address => 192.244.18.9,  
    :port => 25 }
```

I am struggling a lot to find out the issue but no clue. Please help me in figuring out the issue and fixing the issue.
    Thanks a lot.
    --Sreenath

Comment: format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **config/environments/development.rb**
I have add this:

```
#enable using ActionMailer
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }

# enable send mail with specified account
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "yyyyyy",
  :password => "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

and for me work. I hope help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried incorporating those changes in my development.rb file. Still, unable to send mail.

Comment: ... and no one reports any string of error ? look at /var/log. try using sudo find /var/log/ -cmin <seconds>; not even in your web server's log ? try to debug your code and/or post it.

Comment: you use default_protocol: https and in your smtp_settings do not have authentication parameters ... this may be a straight forward !?